# Siteminder: 'Unable to process SMSESSION cookie' for only GET requests

Tags: angularjs, apache, tomcat, siteminder

I have integrated siteminder with my spring application which runs on Tomcat and the front end is developed on AngularJS.
The problem is that after 20 minutes of logging in I am getting error in webagent.log saying **'Unable to process SMSESSION cookie'**.

Interesting point is that it is **happening only for GET requests** and apache is **throwing 302 for these requests**, trying to redirect to SSO login page.
However, for POST requests, I am getting 200 with proper response.
When user is redirected to SSO login page, SSO again redirects to the application without asking to enter login credentials again. And again application works fine for next 20 minutes until GET requests starts failing again.

Does anyone know root-cause/solution of this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have different rules created for GET and POST requests.. What is the idle and maximum timeout value set for the rules.

If you are in a position to enable debug on the webagent, that will tell you exactly why the request is being rejected although from the sound of it, it seems to be an obvious case of session timing out.

Comment: Hi Avi.  I have confirmed that we are not using different rules for GET and POST.<br /> Idle timeout is 20 minutes and maximum timeout is 60 minutes.<br/> But my issue is strange...After 20 minutes, apache starts throwing 302 (redirect to SSO login page) only for GET requests **whether user was idle or not**.